# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) first time

Tags: wordpress, iis-8.5

I am struggling with this issue since sometime :( I have a latest wordpress site installed under IIS 8.5 in Windows Server 2012 R2. Through wordpress admin, few plugins were added. When the website is loaded first time. It appears, few png/jpg, css, php files NOT loading properly. But sometimes reloading the website appears to have fixed the issue.

IIS Server has multiple sites running under it. Most of the websites running under this server has the same issue. Looks like I am missing some critical IIS/Worpress configuration. Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated.

[image: error]

Comment: I wonder when will people stop using Wordpress...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same OS and version. I am by no means an expert, but I think i found a semi-ok solution to this issue. Begin by clicking on settings in the admin portal and find where it says WordPress Address and Site Address. To get the images and links to load correctly, these should be an IP address or a domain name. Because I was just messing around with this in a Virtual machine, I simply set these to the IP of the machine that was hosting the wordpress instance. I'm not sure why this worked but hopefully someone more experienced can fill us in on the details.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. Hope this answer will help somebody. I am no more working on this project. As far as I remember, this issue was not addressed.